# Is it possible to consume a WCF service in MS Access?

Tags: wcf, ms-access

We are thinking about centralising some or all of our data access. I thought a good way to do this would be via WCF. However, lots of our applications are built in MS Access (a whole other story!).

So, is it possible to consume a WCF service in MS Access?

I know consuming web services is possible (although I don't know the details). Is it similar for WCF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but you'd consume them as web services. Just use one of the HTTP bindings for WCF, and it becomes a web service. Simple.

Answer (score 0):

Create a COM Class in dot.net to Access the web service.

**Attention: The App.Config will not readed.**